# Activity looks so different after updating appcompat library to 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I upgraded my v7 appcompat library to 25.0.0, which resulted in my activity suddenly having this weird padding or margin to the left:

[image]

**Edit:** this is how it should look 
[image]

My activity extends AppCompatActivity and here's a little bit of the view xml (activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemBackground="?attr/backgroundColorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/foregroundColorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/foregroundColorPrimary">
        <include layout="@layout/nav_side_bar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tried wrapping my whole layout in a `CoordinatorLayout` and set the `contentInsetLeft` and `contentInsetRight` to 0dp but still no luck...Only seems to happen on my Pixel phone running API 25 (not the XL though)

Comment: the screenshot is of Emulator or android device or the layout preview??

Comment: @AmanVerma screenshot from a real device. Can't be reproduced on an emulator.

Comment: @AmanVerma no those bounds are turned so people can see how messed up this layout is. All that left padding wasn't added by me.

Comment: Have you tried another device? Might be specific to the one tested.

Comment: @KhaledZarrad It's a pixel phone so even if it is specific to this one, I need a fix :(

Answer (score 0):

Use like this standard format.This should be Works for You.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/root">
        -----------------------------------------
        -----PUT YOUR ADDITIONAL LAYOUT HERE-----   
        -----------------------------------------
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">


            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
             </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```